# SQL Server : select nvarchar column with null doesn't return any result

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `dbo.Villa` with this data

[image]

and when I run this query, no results are returned:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Villa v
WHERE v.Section = N'مرکزي'
```

Comment: What editor you are using? SMSS? Other? Maybe character encoding in query editor is not unicode (UTF-8) ?

Comment: with this query 2 rows must be return but no results are returne

Comment: i use microsoft sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is becase of "ي" character in your value. replace it with shift x in persian keyboard layout or change or search with "ی"  like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Villa v
WHERE v.Section = N'مرکزی'
```